# Load a random css file on page load (and remember if possible)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, random

I have 6 different stylesheets, and 1 html page. What i need to do is have the page load one of the stylesheets randomly when it is accessed.

And also, when the user visits and a random stylesheet is loaded, is it possible  to remember which stylesheet was loaded, and only load that stylesheet for that particular visitor (i.e. stop randomising... load the style sheet which was originally loaded)?

I have jQuery loaded into html document.

Comment: Use a cookie to store which stylesheet was loaded. Obviously, you'd check first to see if the user has been there before and a stylesheet was used, to use that one...otherwise grab a random one.

Comment: ok... i think setting a cookie is out of my league... any ideas on the random css?

Comment: Out of your league, how so? Because you don't understand how to manage/work with them? You think it isn't smart/secure? It isn't allowed in your situation?

Comment: no idea how to work with them... that would have been a nice benefit to have, but not too important (as i don't expect people to come back to the site)

Comment: They really aren't hard to work with, and even easier if you use a special library. Just take a look at the answers, they provide (easy) ways to do this with cookies.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  var userStylesheet = $.cookie('user_stylesheet');

  if(!userStylesheet){
    userStylesheet = Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1);
    $.cookie('user_stylesheet', userStylesheet);
  }

  var ss = $('<link/>').attr('rel', 'stylesheet').attr('type','text/css').attr('href', 'stylesheet' + userStylesheet + '.css');
  $(document.body).append(ss);

});

</script>
</head>
<body>
  Hello!
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

Here's the link for the [jquery.cookie.js RAW](https://raw.github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/jquery.cookie.js)

Comment: thanks for this... where do i list the 6 available stylesheets and their locations?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any kind of server-side scripting at your disposal? If so I would decide which CSS file to serve on the server, and save the value in a session variable—then if that session variable is set on subsequent page loads, output it instead of generating a new one.

Alternatively, you can try [setting a cookie in javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) or [local storage.](http://html5please.com/#localStorage)